# Mysql : how to deal with categories having their own attributes

Tags: mysql, filter, attributes

Lets say I have a store which sells general products... for example bikes and computers. An item can have only one category.

So I have items which have a category (bikes, computers, clothes, etc), and depending on the category the item has attributes, and those attributes have values also depending on the category.

For example I have a

- "sweater" that have the category "clothes" and its attributes may be : **size** with value "*M*" and **color** with value "*blue*"
- "netbook" that have the category "computer" and its attributes may be : **CPU** with value "*Core i3*" and memory with value "*1 To*"

What would be a good approach to this? So far I haven't so much... just a table "items" and "category" ... maybe "filter" but not sure.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would do an EAV. You need to do more research. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you. I read some stuff on the EAV but it seems very complicated anyway. There be a solution a little less heavy?

Comment: you might take a look at nosql